# Is there a character limit to items listed in a drop-down menu?

Tags: usability, forms, drop-down-list, best-practice

I am not asking about max or min. number of items listed but rather how long each item should or can be?

My client is using a drop down menu to provide answers to a  question. The options (answers) are quite lengthy. I don't think a drop down is the right way to go.

[image]

Comment: do you have a mock? is this a form or something that provides canned answers?

Comment: I added a mockup. It's a form. One of many questions. Some answers are even longer.

Answer (score 3):

The first question to ask in a scenario like this: is a drop-down menu the best option for my use case?

If you need to list a lot of options in a compact manner, few UI elements are better than a drop-down. However, multi-line options are not ideal.

Consider other options, such as paragraphs with radio button selections (see below). It will increase the page length, but will allow users to fully read each option without opening anything.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpE0aP.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think your question has 2 parts.

Technically speaking, it's unlimited. The default max-length is 524288 (which equals 512K)

However, the real question you're asking is if this is the best choice. And then the answer is **NO, IT'S NOT**. Your best choice is a radio list, and if you want to keep the dropdown feeling, or if you have space constraints, just use an [**accordion**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/accordions-complex-content/)

EDIT: Now I see Alan just answered with the list of items with `input type=radio`. That's what I meant, so I'll add the accordion part :)